# electron frameless window auto maximize when drag to the top (windows 7)

Tags: electron

a normal program, when mouse click and drag windows topbar to the top of screen, this program will auto fullscreen in windows 7+ system

but when I use electron without the frame, and use electron-drag package to control move it, then, what can I do, to let it auto fullscreen when drag to top, and drag left side cover left screen, drag right side...

thanks

Answer (score 1):

electron-drag hasn't been updated for 2 years.

Why not just use electrons built in drag-able style `<div style="-webkit-app-region: drag">` I Built a quick app, and added the style to a div, worked fine.

https://electronjs.org/docs/api/frameless-window#draggable-region

```
Note: -webkit-app-region: drag is known to have problems while the developer tools are open.
See this GitHub issue for more information including a workaround.
```

**EDIT:**
create a quick gist showing how to mimic the snapping of a frameless window without using the draggable style. https://gist.github.com/flapjack17/44a9fdd504b832714c24f899a11c0b42

Comment: thanks for reply, first time I used "-webkit-app-region: drag" method to drag windows, but I can't disable right click on drag area, so I change to use electron-drag package, Is there any way to use and disable right click, thanks

Comment: Ah, now  I see why. the problem with the electron-drag is it doesn't actually use the window title bar, so it's not triggering the areosnap feature. I will make an edit to my answer to a gist I made, it's quick and dirt, but I might turn it in to an electron nom module since it looks like there hasn't been any movement on electron-drag.

Comment: Upvoted because it does not make sense that the only person who tries to be helpful gets downvoted.